# Firebase push notification not received on foreground

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I setup an app according to Firebase docs and it works only when app is is in background.

But when my app is running on foreground, I can't receive any notification.

I googled it, but no solution found. Any help is appreciated.

Here are the details:

1) Manifests File:

```
<service
            android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service
            android:name=".FirebaseIDService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@drawable/unselected_gift" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
            android:resource="@color/white" />

+ Permissions
```

2)

```
class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService:

private static final String TAG = "FCM Service";
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        // TODO: Handle FCM messages here.
        // If the application is in the foreground handle both data and notification messages here.
        // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
        // message, here is where that should be initiated.
        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
        Log.d(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());

        // ...

        // TODO(developer): Handle FCM messages here.
        // Not getting messages here? See why this may be:
        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

        // Check if message contains a data payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
        }

        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }

        // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
        // message, here is where that should be initiated. See sendNotification method below.
    }
```

3)

```
class FirebaseIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService :

private static final String TAG = "FirebaseIDService";

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        // Get updated InstanceID token.
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);

        // If you want to send messages to this application instance or
        // manage this apps subscriptions on the server side, send the
        // Instance ID token to your app server.
        sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
    }

    /**
     * Persist token to third-party servers.
     *
     * Modify this method to associate the user's FCM InstanceID token with any server-side account
     * maintained by your application.
     *
     * @param token The new token.
     */
    private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
        // Add custom implementation, as needed.
    }
```

4) Gradle (app)

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

5)Gradle (Project):

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
}
```

Comment: @android_griezmann that linked question is about not receiving notification messages when the app is backgrounded. This one is specifically about when the app is in the foreground.

Comment: @Sagar: what's the problem? Don't the logging messages show up in logcat?

Comment: Your device is a Huawei or Xiaomi?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Ya right my bad!

Comment: No Yu Yureka    @Merlí Escarpenter Pérez

Comment: D/Status line: 200
D/FCM Service: From: 692735825094
D/FCM Service: Notification Message Body: +917276713577
I/PVL: RECEIVED MESSAGE: +917276713577
D/FCM Service: From: 692735825094
D/FCM Service: Message Notification Body: +917276713577
V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service

Comment: Guys this is not a duplicate; the problem is when the app is in the FOREGROUND, not background.

Comment: Just add custom notification in MyFirebaseMessagingService if it received.
Also add some key+value to notification.